# using Htmlagility pack to find a div from html string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html-agility-pack

I have a table where in one column, I have saved all the html of a page. I want to fetch a div( and its contents) from that div using htmlagility how can I do this. I don't want to load it from url or do screen scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Load your html

HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
// Find div with an id or you could use a class if you want
var nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='myDivId']");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution.

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(@html);

            HtmlNodeCollection tableRows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr");

            string content = "";
            if (tableRows.Count > 1)
            {
                HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='account-detail']");
               content = node.InnerHtml;
            }
```

thank you all for your time.